# Owl Carousel Arrows not changing

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Here is my css right now for the arrows. When I use this the arrows are just the same gray color. The picture doesn't show. I have tried messing with the owl theme css by changing opacity but it didn't help. Is there something I'm doing wrong or not doing? Here is the picture I am trying to change it to. I downloaded it and put it in my images. http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/symbols/elusive/dev/svg/chevron-right.svg

Begin arrows. I wrote this css by naming navigationText ins the JS file to icon-arrow-left and icon-arrow-right.

```
 .icon-arrow-left {
        background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 44px;
        width: 44px;
        margin-right: 8px; 
    }

     .icon-arrow-left:hover {
        background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png"); 
     }

     .icon-arrow-right {
        background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 44px;
        width: 44px;
        margin-left: 8px; 
     }

       .icon-arrow-right:hover {
        background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png");
    }
```

end arrows

```
Here is the JS file for it 

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  singleItem:true,
  transitionStyle:'fade',
  navigationText: ['<div class="icon-arrow-left"></div>', 
  '<div class="icon-arrow-right"></div>'],
  });

});
```

Comment: Hint: your `hover` does not make sense - nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console - is there any errors? Double check img src in css.

I tested owl-carousel and everything works perfect (scroll down - navigation is under slider):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay : 3000,
    stopOnHover : true,
    navigation:true,
    singleItem : true,
    autoHeight : true,
    navigationText: ['<div class="left">left</div>', '<div class="right">right</div>']
  });
 
});
```

```css
.left {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/20x20") left center no-repeat;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.right {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/20x20") right center no-repeat;
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see any console errors, and the file path should be correct. I tried using an img link to try it too. The image doesn't go on the arrow and is still gray

Comment: Try replace your `backgorund-image` with `background: url("http://placehold.it/20x20");` for tests - mayby your path is invalid. 

Check in dev-tools that `<div class="icon-arrow-left"></div>` is insterted to DOM - mayby your JS code does not work.

Comment: Ok the pictures you linked showed. It's very transparent but I can sorta see it. I believe I did the file paths correctly though, do you think it could be the image not showing correctly?

Comment: EDIT: I must not be doing file paths correctly. I linked another image and it worked. Also another quick question. What's the best way to position the arrows at the top and make it responsive?

Comment: Arrows on the top of the slider - add to css file:
`.owl-controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}`